# Turning IP address into coordinates?

Tags: python, ip, coordinates, folium

I'm right now working on a project which is a map, using `folium`. Until I realized, that I needed to get `longitude` and `latitude`. I tried using [ipconfig](https://ipinfo.io/)  and [opencagedata](https://opencagedata.com/) but the output was my routers `IPv4 Address`. Therefore, I switched to *socket*, and it gave me a result. But now, I can't find a way to convert that specific string into coordinates.

**Here is a simplified preview of it:**

```py
import folium;
Map = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=10)
folium.Marker([latitude, longitude], popup=location).add_to(Map)
Map.save("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop\\location.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `freegeoapi` API: https://freegeoip.app/

Comment: I tried this ``https://freegeoip.app/json/IP_ADDRESS``, but there was nothing. Is my location, privated?

Comment: Is the IP address you're testing with a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) (i.e. in one of the ranges: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255, 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255)?

Comment: Yes, make sure you are testing your public IP, not your local IP

Comment: You can use https://whatismyipaddress.com/ to get your public IP

Comment: And usual warning: do no trust too much such services. It is very difficult to know the exact location. Companies may uses own IP blocks (and so registered possibly in an other country). Mobile phones may have problems too. Also there is no official source, so all data are guesses. But for statistics you can use it without much troubles.